# hadoop word count example where does reducer output go?

Tags: hadoop

I have a map/reduce I am looking at on cassandra and it has this line in the reducer

context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));

and I would like to see the full list of keys and their total count.  Where do I go to get this information.

as an example, I see the word count example but see no code for outputting stuff to the screen but somehow it does output stuff to the screen.  Where is my output for my map/reduce going then?

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v2.0

thanks,
Dean

Comment: ... It "outputs stuff to the screen" because it runs `cat` via HDFS. The file is wherever you've defined your HDFS to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Map/Reduce output goes to an output directory in HDFS that you define in your code or as a runtime parameter, or in your job configuration file.